# Issues with tabactivity and mainactivity using service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-service, android-tabactivity

hi i have my app aacplayer but im trying to implement a tab menu i achieved that but my issue here when my app opens have to run MainActivity.java but that one have a service of audio but i added anothers tabs and works perfect that ones doesnt use services.

here is the log of error:

```
02-14 19:24:11.685: E/AndroidRuntime(31027): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=STARTED flg=0x10 } in com.webcraftbd.radio.MainActivity$RadioUpdateReceiver@42e09468
```

tabactivity.java:

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("En Vivo");
        photospec.setIndicator("En Vivo", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Twitter");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        songspec.setIndicator("Twitter", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contactenos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Contactenos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab

        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);
            tv.setShadowLayer(2, 2, 2, Color.BLACK);
        } 

    }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{     

    private static boolean displayAd;

    private Button playButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private Button stopButton;
    private Button nextButton;
    private Button previousButton;
    private ImageView stationImageView;

    private TextView albumTextView;
    private TextView artistTextView;
    private TextView trackTextView;
    private TextView statusTextView;    
    private TextView timeTextView;

    private Intent bindIntent;
    private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
    private boolean wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall = false;
    private RadioUpdateReceiver radioUpdateReceiver;
    private RadioService radioService;
    private AdView adView;

    private String STATUS_BUFFERING;
    private static final String TYPE_AAC = "aac";
    private static final String TYPE_MP3 = "mp3";
    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;

    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initControls();
        // Bind to the service  
        try {
            bindIntent = new Intent(this, RadioService.class);
            bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }

        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(telephonyManager != null) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

        handler = new Handler();

        initialize();       
    }

    private void initControls() {
        try {
            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

            volumeSeekbar
                    .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0,
                                int progress, boolean arg2) {
                            audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            int index = volumeSeekbar.getProgress();
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(index + 1);
            return false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            int index = volumeSeekbar.getProgress();
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(index - 1);
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT || newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            try {

                handler.post( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        initialize();

                        if(radioService.getTotalStationNumber()<=1) {
                            nextButton.setEnabled(false);
                            nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            previousButton.setEnabled(false);
                            previousButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        updateStatus();
                        updateMetadata();
                        //updateAlbum();

                        System.out.println("radioService.isPreparingStarted() = "+radioService.isPreparingStarted());                           
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        try {

            displayAd = (boolean) Boolean.parseBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.is_display_ad));

            STATUS_BUFFERING = getResources().getString(R.string.status_buffering);

            playButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
            pauseButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.PauseButton);
            stopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StopButton);   
            nextButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
            previousButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.PreviousButton);
            pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            stationImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stationImageView);

            playButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);

            albumTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.albumTextView);
            artistTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.artistTextView);
            trackTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.trackTextView);
            statusTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.statusTextView);
            timeTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);


            startService(new Intent(this, RadioService.class));

            displayAd();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void displayAd() {
        if(displayAd==true) {
            // Create the adView
            try {

                if (adView != null) {
                  adView.destroy();
                }

                adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, this.getString(R.string.admob_publisher_id));
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
                layout.addView(adView);
                adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0));
            layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void updatePlayTimer() {
        timeTextView.setText(radioService.getPlayingTime());

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {   
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {    
                        timeTextView.setText(radioService.getPlayingTime());                        
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000);        
    }


    public void onClickPlayButton(View view) {
        radioService.play();
    }

    public void onClickPauseButton(View view) {
        radioService.pause();
    }

    public void onClickStopButton(View view) {      
        radioService.stop();
        //resetMetadata();
        //updateDefaultCoverImage();
    }

    public void onClickNextButton(View view) {
        resetMetadata();
        playNextStation();
        //updateDefaultCoverImage();        
    }

    public void onClickPreviousButton(View view) {
        resetMetadata();
        playPreviousStation();
        //updateDefaultCoverImage();                
    }

    public void playNextStation() {
        radioService.stop();
        radioService.setNextStation();      

        /*
        if(radioService.isPlaying()) {
            radioService.setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
            updateStatus();
            radioService.stop();
            radioService.play();
        }
        else {
            radioService.stop();
        }
        */
    }

    public void playPreviousStation() {
        radioService.stop();
        radioService.setPreviousStation();      

        /*
        if(radioService.isPlaying()) {
            radioService.setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
            updateStatus();
            radioService.stop();
            radioService.play();
        }
        else {
            radioService.stop();
        }
        */
    }

    public void updateDefaultCoverImage() {

        String mDrawableName = "station_"+(radioService.getCurrentStationID()+1);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());

        stationImageView.setImageResource(resID);
        albumTextView.setText("");
    }

    public void updateAlbum() {

        String album = radioService.getAlbum();
        String artist = radioService.getArtist();
        String track = radioService.getTrack();
        Bitmap albumCover = radioService.getAlbumCover();

        albumTextView.setText(album);

        if(albumCover==null || (artist.equals("") && track.equals("")))
            updateDefaultCoverImage();
        else {
            stationImageView.setImageBitmap(albumCover);
            radioService.setAlbum(LastFMCover.album);

            if(radioService.getAlbum().length() + radioService.getArtist().length()>50) {
                albumTextView.setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateMetadata() {
        String artist = radioService.getArtist();
        String track = radioService.getTrack();
        //if(artist.length()>30)
            //artist = artist.substring(0, 30)+"...";
        artistTextView.setText(artist);
        trackTextView.setText(track);
        albumTextView.setText("");
    }

    public void resetMetadata() {
        radioService.resetMetadata();
        artistTextView.setText("");
        albumTextView.setText("");
        trackTextView.setText("");
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if(radioService!=null) {
            if(!radioService.isPlaying() && !radioService.isPreparingStarted()) {
                //radioService.stopSelf();
                radioService.stopService(bindIntent);
            }
        }           

        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }

        if(telephonyManager != null) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (radioUpdateReceiver != null) 
            unregisterReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();

        /* Register for receiving broadcast messages */
        if (radioUpdateReceiver == null) radioUpdateReceiver = new RadioUpdateReceiver();   
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_CREATED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_DESTROYED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_START_PREPARING));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_PREPARED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_PLAYING));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_PAUSED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_STOPPED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_COMPLETED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_ERROR));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_START));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_END));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_METADATA_UPDATED));
        registerReceiver(radioUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(RadioService.MODE_ALBUM_UPDATED));

        if(wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall) {
            radioService.play();
            wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall = false;
        }
    }

    /* Receive Broadcast Messages from RadioService */
    private class RadioUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_CREATED)) {

            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_DESTROYED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //updateDefaultCoverImage();
                updateMetadata();
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_STARTED)) {                
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);              
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);              

                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                updateStatus();             
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_START_PREPARING)) {                
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);              
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);              
                playButton.setEnabled(false);           
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_PREPARED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_START)) {
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_BUFFERING_END)) {
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if (intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_PLAYING)) {
                if(radioService.getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC)) {
                    playButton.setEnabled(false);
                    stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else {
                    playButton.setEnabled(false);
                    pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
                    stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_PAUSED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_STOPPED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_COMPLETED)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_ERROR)) {
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                updateStatus();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_METADATA_UPDATED)) {
                updateMetadata();
                updateStatus();
                //updateDefaultCoverImage();
            }
            else if(intent.getAction().equals(RadioService.MODE_ALBUM_UPDATED)) {
                //updateAlbum();
            }
        }
    }

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall = radioService.isPlaying();
                radioService.stop();
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if(wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall) {
                    radioService.play();
                }
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                wasPlayingBeforePhoneCall = radioService.isPlaying();
                radioService.stop();
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };


    public void updateStatus() {
        String status = radioService.getStatus();
        if(radioService.getTotalStationNumber() > 1) {
            if(status!="")
                status = radioService.getCurrentStationName()+" - "+status;
            else
                status = radioService.getCurrentStationName();
        }

        try {   
                statusTextView.setText(status);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Handles the connection between the service and activity
    private ServiceConnection radioConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            radioService = ((RadioService.RadioBinder)service).getService();

            if(radioService.getTotalStationNumber()<=1) {
                nextButton.setEnabled(false);
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                previousButton.setEnabled(false);
                previousButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            updateStatus();
            updateMetadata();
            //updateAlbum();
            updatePlayTimer();
            radioService.showNotification();
            //radioService.play();

        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            radioService = null;
        }
    };

}
```

baseactivity.java:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private Intent bindIntent;
    private RadioService radioService;

    private static boolean isExitMenuClicked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        isExitMenuClicked = false;

        // Bind to the service  
        bindIntent = new Intent(this, RadioService.class);
        bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();
        if(isExitMenuClicked==true)
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent i;

        final String thisClassName = this.getClass().getName();
        final String thisPackageName = this.getPackageName();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.radio:
            if(!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName+".MainActivity")) {
                i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.facebook:
            if(!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName+".FacebookActivity")) {
                i = new Intent(this, FacebookActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.twitter:
            if(!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName+".TwitterActivity")) {
                i = new Intent(this, TwitterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            if(!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName+".AboutActivity")) {
                i = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            String title = "Exit Radio";
            String message = "Desea salir de la aplicacion?";
            String buttonYesString = "Si";
            String buttonNoString = "No";

            isExitMenuClicked = true;

            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            //ad.setTitle(title);
            ad.setMessage(message);
            ad.setCancelable(true);
            ad.setPositiveButton(buttonYesString, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                    

                    if(radioService!=null) {
                        radioService.exitNotification();
                        radioService.stop();                        
                        radioService.stopService(bindIntent);                       
                        isExitMenuClicked = true;
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });

            ad.setNegativeButton(buttonNoString, null);

            ad.show();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Handles the connection between the service and activity
    private ServiceConnection radioConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            radioService = ((RadioService.RadioBinder)service).getService();            
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            radioService = null;
        }
    };


}
```

I dont know what else i can do to fix my main activity.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

In MainActivity.java, this code must be as below;

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```